# Relating two database tables (associating an employee with an activity)

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am trying to develop a database to store data collected by a web based application that tracks employee activities.  I have an employee table that looks like this

```
Employee
--------
id
name
position
email
```

And and multiple activity tables, each with different columns.  An example of one:

```
OutreachAndTraining
-----
id
date
county
city
type
...

ProfessionalDevelopment
------
id
date
comments
```

I want to be able to keep track of which employees were a part of each activity but only want to log the activity itself once.  What is the best way to associate multiple employees with one activity?  Will I have to create a separate table for each activity to store employee IDs and activity IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an employee can take part in more than one activity, what you have here is an N:M relationship between employees and activities, which is modeled with the additional "link" table per each relationship:

[image]

---

If you have many kinds of activities, you may consider inheritance (aka. category, generalization, subtype or class hierarchy), to minimize the number of relationships (and therefore "link" tables):

[image]

For more information on inheritance, search for "Subtype Relationships" in [ERwin Methods Guide](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20Data%20Modeler%20r8-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/ERwin_Methods.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks for this example.  I was having a hard time visualizing the link tables and was wondering if that was the only possible solution.  Looks like subtypes might be the best way to go.

Comment: Ok, this all makes sense to me as far as retrieving entries from the database but I am still having trouble determining how to go about entering this info and what the SQL query might look like.

Comment: ... to log an activity for multiple employees. 

I am autoincrementing my IDs for the activity tables so how will I know what to insert to the EmployeeActivity table for ActivityID before the activity has even been inserted?

Comment: @jasontk19 Obviously, you need to discover what `id` was generated when row was inserted in `Activity`, before you can insert it in `EmployeeActivity.ActivityId`. This is done either by separating the `id` generation from the insertion (on DBMSes that support sequences: generate new `id` from the sequence, insert it into `Activity`, then insert the _same_ `id` into `EmployeeActivity`) or by returning the newly generated `id` directly from the INSERT statement, typically through something like `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` or `INSERT ... OUTPUT ...`.

Comment: @jasontk19 Less commonly, you could even choose the type for `id` such that it can be uniquely generated in advance by the client (e.g. GUID). This has its pros (easy and portable) and cons (more storage-hungry than plain int, index fragmentation).

Comment: Did some looking around and found that MySQL has a `LAST_INSERT_ID()`command that does exactly what I need.  Thanks again!